# Invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2016-04-22'

Tags: python

This error is killing me and I'm hoping some of you can help.

To start I am processing amazon order reports for a client.

I'm pulling out the order dates which consist of the usual YYYY-MM-DD H:M:S plus the timezone code. The datetimes are going into a list and I'm iterating over the list like so:

```
temps = list()
for date_time in date_times:
    temps.append(str(date_time).split('T'))
```

Then I'm iterating through the split up date times and appending each to a separate list.

```
dates = list()
times = list()
for temp in temps:
    dates.append(temp[0])
    times.append(temp[1])
```

In my code, I keep getting this error:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2016-04-22'
```

I know this happens when trying to convert a string or empty string to an `int` however, all I'm doing is appending the damn thing to a list. What is stranger is that this script has been running for over a month without a problem, so I'm at a loss at this point as to why it started doing this suddenly.

The script is on pythonanywhere and is set to run automatically with the necessary packages installed within a virtualenv so everything else about the setup is static. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Here's the mvce. Apologies for not providing one initially.
You can get the [files I'm using from this link.](http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=geb9d53c5a480d3069998187956412a53dd09159f4) They perform as their names suggest. `good.txt` parses fine and `bad.txt` throws the error. Use `scratchpad.py` to parse the text files. The contents of the two text files are normally read into memory directly from the Amazon servers and processed from there. The files at the above link are downloaded directly from Amazon and all I've done is removed non-essential information from them.

Here is the stack traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jason/.virtualenvs/sw/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2885, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-18-4d933b0787fe>", line 1, in <module>
    f = parse_report('/home/jason/Desktop/bad.txt')
  File "<ipython-input-17-420ad5606095>", line 57, in parse_report
    report.loc[:, 'purchase-date'] = dates
  File "/home/jason/.virtualenvs/sw/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 115, in __setitem__
    self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
  File "/home/jason/.virtualenvs/sw/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 473, in _setitem_with_indexer
    setter(labels[0], value)
  File "/home/jason/.virtualenvs/sw/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 416, in setter
    s._data = s._data.setitem(indexer=pi, value=v)
  File "/home/jason/.virtualenvs/sw/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 2734, in setitem
    return self.apply('setitem', **kwargs)
  File "/home/jason/.virtualenvs/sw/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 2710, in apply
    applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
  File "/home/jason/.virtualenvs/sw/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 585, in setitem
    values, value = self._try_coerce_args(self.values, value)
  File "/home/jason/.virtualenvs/sw/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 1929, in _try_coerce_args
    other = np.array(other, dtype='i8')
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2016-04-22'
```

EDIT #2:
`pandas = '0.17.0'`

Comment: Please give a [mcve] and the full traceback.

Comment: Doesn't look like the code you posted could cause the error - can you post the full traceback and a bit more of your code to make an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sure, I'll try and put something together. The problem is the reports contain customer information which I (obviously) won't share here and the total code is over 1000 lines and interacts with the amazon server

Comment: `int` requires the parameter to contain only valid characters. For base 10, only `0-9`.

Comment: don't share all code, traceback got line identify, @jonrsharpe mean part of code and traceback!

Comment: Hence a **minimal**, complete and verifiable example...

Comment: Which, by the way, you were expected to post in the first place to (a) show that you've done your debugging before posting, and (b) avoid all this entirely unnecessary back-and-forth in the comments.

Comment: Each adjective in "minimal, complete, and verifiable" is important.  It should be minimal so that we don't have to weed through your code to find the problem.  It should be complete so that we don't need to come up with our own code and hope that it is the same as yours.  It should verifiable so that we can easily get more information about the error and the situation, and so that we can guarantee that our answers fix the problem.

Comment: @JRichardSnape See above for mcve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to fix the script. It only happens when the report contains a single order. Furthermore, it only happens when I'm attempting to replace that single timestamp in my dataframe. So there is something amiss between re-assigning values to an existing series/column and the way that takes place when there is a dataframe with a single row.

The solution is to insert a new column for the hours and minutes and use string-from-time to format appropriately:

```
df.insert(loc=10,
          column='purchase-time',
          value=df.loc[:, 'purchase-date'].dt.strftime("%H:%M"))
```

Then rename the existing column (which will be deleted later):

```
df = df.rename(columns={'purchase-date': 'old-purchase-date'})
```

The insert another column and format as needed:

```
df.insert(loc=2,
          column='purchase-date',
          value=df.loc[:, 'old-purchase-date'].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Now the column can be dropped:

```
df = df.drop('old-purchase-date',
             axis=1)
```

This works for reports with a single order or multiple orders. Thank you all for your help and suggestions, you were all very constructive, helpful and just plain awesome, I learned a lot from you ;)

Answer (score -1):

Use the datetime-Module to parse datetimes:

```
date_and_times = []
for date_time in date_times:
    date_and_times.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'))
```

And don't split things up into different lists, that belong together like dates and times.